# Storing an HTML node as key in an *object*

Tags: javascript, object, properties, reference, key

Similar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858493/storing-html-nodes-as-key-in-array), I would like to use HTML nodes as keys in an *object* (not an array).

Example:

```
var _hotspots = {
                 [object HTMLDivElement] : { someProps:[1,2,3] },
                 [object HTMLDivElement] : { someProps:[1,2,3] }
                }
```

and so I might achieve things like this:

```
for( var a in _hotspots ){
    if(YAHOO.lang.hasOwnProperty(_hotspots, a)){
    alert('key nodeName: '+a.nodeName);
    }
}
```

So far, when I alert out 'a' above, it alerts out that it is in fact a [object HTMLDivElement], so it all seemed fine - but I can't access properties on 'a', like nodeName.

Is what I am doing possible? Is it wrong? If I should be able to access properties on the object's key reference then please let me know and I'll write up a sample page.

cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keys of JavaScript objects are always character.  You could store the id as the key and then retreive the element in your function.

Comment: Ok, I suspected this would be the case - thanks for confirmation. Actually, while I'm at it, is there a fundamental reason for this? Or is it just the way it is?

Comment: That is the structure of the object (so ya, just the way it is).

Comment: If you assign a non-string as a property name, it is first converted to string. So assigning a DOM element is like assigning `element.toString()` as the name.

Comment: Cheers Rob, that might explain why when I tried for(b in a){} earlier, I received a bunch of numbers from 0 to (whatever it was), character indices I'm guessing?

Answer (score 6):

It's now possible to do this with [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) objects, but a Map is more appropriate if you want to store key value pair, such as a regular object.

You could still add node as key with regular objects, but the problem is that the node is converted to a string, because objects can only store keys as strings, this means that the object can't distinguish unique nodes that have identical attributes/structure.

The reason `Map` works is because its keys can be any value, including functions, objects, or any primitive.

```js
const divEl1 = document.querySelectorAll("div")[0];
const divEl2 = document.querySelectorAll("div")[1];

const obj = {};
const map = new Map();

obj[divEl1] = divEl1.getBoundingClientRect();
map.set(divEl1, divEl1.getBoundingClientRect());

console.log("Object: is divEl1? ", !!obj[divEl2]);
console.log("Map: is divEl1? ", map.has(divEl2));
console.log("Map: get divEl1 bounding properties", map.get(divEl1));
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="foo" data-some-id="1">I am a <span>div</span></div>
  <div class="foo" data-some-id="1">I am a <span>div</span></div>
</body>
```

You can also use [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) and [`WeakSet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet) to add node as keys. Using `Map`/`Set`, to store elements poses a potential memory issue once elements are removed from DOM, because they are still held in `Map`/`Set` and are not garbage collected. When using `WeakMap`/`WeakSet`, if no other references to those elements stored in those objects exist, those elements will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

You could use my own [jshashtable](http://code.google.com/p/jshashtable/), which accepts any object as key, but if it's not a problem for you to give all your elements an `id` then I'd recommend using an object with element IDs as keys, since that will be the simplest and most performant solution.

Comment: Thanks Tim, will check that out tomorrow and have a look. In my case I'd already generated IDs for each node being used as a key (or now as a 'node' key in an object value of its own 'id' key). I quite like the idea of being able to use the object as key.