# Can I use HTML elements as Object keys?

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, object, dom

I'm trying to create an Object with HTML elements as keys. I create the keys using `document.createElement('div')`, but when I try to insert both into an Object the second key ends up replacing the first:

```js
let a = document.createElement('div');
let b = document.createElement('div');

let obj = {};
obj[a] = 3;
obj[b] = 'x';

console.log(obj);
```

Is there a way to do this without any keys or values getting replaced?

Comment: what are you trying to do , what is your use case ?

Comment: You could use `Map` instead of an plain object.

Comment: This question was asked me on interview. But, couldn't find answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209581/storing-an-html-node-as-key-in-an-object

Comment: What exactly was the interview question? Pretty sure you misunderstood what they wanted.

Comment: @GuyIncognito Interview was related coding task, But, at last he asked me same question that How can I solve this? I gave answer that we can give one unique value as key in combination with div element.

Comment: Asked what? There is no question there.

Comment: Whenever a key is added to an object, it internally does `String(key)`. Both `String(a)` and `String(b)` return `"[object HTMLDivElement]"`. It's still unclear what the question is. Did your interview ask how can we use an HTML element as the key of an object?

Comment: @adiga I edited question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Objects can only hold string keys. Your `div`s are being serialized to strings and then overriding each other. If you would like to hold HTML Elements as keys you should use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) like so:

```js
let a = document.createElement('div');
let b = document.createElement('div');

let map = new Map();
map.set(a, 3);
map.set(b, 'x');

// use Array.from to pretty print the result
console.log(Array.from(map));
```

Comment: Just `Array.from(map)` is enough to return the entries :)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `a` to create a key in an `object`

```
let a = document.createElement('div');
obj[a] = 3;
```

It assigns the `object` the string representation of `a` which is `"[object HTMLDivElement]"`

```
console.log(obj); // { "[object HTMLDivElement]": 3 }
```

So when you assign `b`

```
obj[b] = 'x';
```

what you're really saying is

```
obj["[object HTMLDivElement]"] = 'x'
```

and `"[object HTMLDivElement]"` already exists in the object, so it assigns it the new value of `'x'`

```
console.log(obj); // { "[object HTMLDivElement]": "x" }
```

Comment: I know about that but, I want any alternative way So, I can achieve result.

Comment: You clearly didn't know about it. If you knew about this, then you wouldn't try this as a solution. If you want an alternative [look at the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61957129/2418790).